# Which SCM for GNU/Smalltalk?

Tags: version-control, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I have been exploring different source code management tools for Smalltalk dialects, and as Pharo has Monticello and Metacello, VisualWorks has Parcels, and VisualAge uses Envy/Developer.

Which source code management tools is used primarily in GNU/Smalltalk for development of user projects? (not the development of GST itself)

Comment: The language and version control are independent. You can use any version control system with any language. Git is probably the most popular SCM these days and I would highly recommend it.

Comment: The Smalltalk language and its environment are NOT independent (event if you could define formally both separately), so your ECLECTIC workflows so typical of fashioned languages do not count here. Please interact with a Smalltalk environment to get an idea of what's been asked here.

Comment: I think you are confusing "SCM" and "IDE". SCM simply implies version control. And GNU Smalltalk, unlike these other variants of Smalltalk that you reference, does not bake the compiler/interpreter into the IDE. GNU Smalltalk is just the interpreter; you can use whatever IDE you want, and you can store the files in any normal version control system that you want.

Comment: The question is about a SCM appliable to GNU Smalltalk, such as Parcels are appliable to VisualWorks (see paper here http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1477842405000072). Although I can understand your passional feelings about Git-like tools (like everybody today), they are seen as a step back for most experienced Smalltalkers. Unfortunately, 300 characters are not enough to explain the Smalltalk typical workflow. To make a point, hardly any Smalltalker would say "you can use whatever IDE you want" because everyone knows that the environment "hides" compiler, interpreter, etc.

Comment: @user869097 I think your comment is correct for any Smalltalk but GNU Smalltalk :)

Comment: True, but now there is VisualGST which start to look nice

Comment: Ah, i was not aware of VisualGST. Does it affect that code is stored in files?

Comment: You can create files with Pharo you can use another IDE for Pharo (i.e see shampoo for emacs) and you can use Git with Pharo. You can do pretty much anything with Pharo. There is actually a very nice lib for Git and documentation how to use it here --> https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/PharoForTheEnterprise/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/GitAndPharo/GitAndPharo.pier.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU Smalltalk boils down to plain files as most of the other languages do, you are free to use any versioning system that works with files. Like [git](/questions/tagged/git), [hg](/questions/tagged/hg), [svn](/questions/tagged/svn), [cvs](/questions/tagged/cvs) and more